# How to configure codeblocks?

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

Why doesn't codeblock find a compiler? I previously tried to install codeblocks(without the mingw setup) into my c: and tried to configure cygwin for it and since I was unsuccessful, I completely uninstalled codeblocks and  downloaded the codeblocks with the mingw setup and installed it on my E:, which I thought would have been preconfigured, but the settings from the older one remained:

[image]
I had downloaded the mingw setup and installed it on my E: :
[image]

Since I had the cygwin gcc as the selected compiler, but the site mentioned that the mingw setup had gcc/g++ compiler and debugger, I(thought) I would have to select one from the list but there were many, so I just selected one:

[image]
But the compiler always produces an error message:
[image]
If the compiler was included within the installer, shouldn't it had configured the path itself? How do I configure codeblocks so that I can start compiling c codes?

Comment: Just out of interest: do you develop for the Lattice 8 MCU (http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/DesignSoftwareAndIP/IntellectualProperty/IPCore/IPCores02/Mico8 )? I think you need to install that separately, the installer has only an older version of TDM-GCC included (32/64 bit only and AFAIK not for all architectures).

Comment: @deamentiaemundi, no actually I don't know anything at all, I'm just starting out for programming, and have not been able to find a decent easy-to-use compiler. Dev c++ was easy to use but it contains so many bugs that I didn't want to use. How do I use the TDM-GCC included with the installer. I just want to compile some programs(just toy programs at my level)

Comment: IDE != compiler. But as deamentiaemundi suggested, you'll have to select the compiler you have. Just picking a random one won't help. Also, why not just grab Visual Studio and get on with coding?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I pointed that I downloaded the one that had mingw included, if so which would be the one from the list above that I'd have to select? How do I configure codeblock?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, codeblock is what I have at the moment, I'd like to configure it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the codeblocks installer failed to setup mingw for you, here's how you can manually add it.  In the global compiler settings dialog that you're showing above:

- Select "GNU GCC Compiler" (it should be the very first option).
- Select the "Toolchain executables" tab
- Try hitting the autodetect button.  That may or may not work if you have multiple versions of mingw/tdm-gcc on your computer.
- If it doesn't work:

  - hit the "..." button and manually choose the root folder of the mingw version you want to use.  (It's the folder that contains the bin, include, and lib subfolders).  Call that folder MINGWROOT.
  - select the "Search directories" tab, and then select the "Compiler" subtab.  Hit the add button and enter MINGWROOT\include
  - select the "Linker" subtab, hit the add button and enter MINGWROOT\lib
  - select the "Resource compiler" subtab, hit the add button and enter MINGWROOT\include

Now whenever you start a new project, when you get to the wizard screen that says something like "Please select the compiler to use...", select "GNU GCC Compiler" (again it should be the first option).

Comment: The installer only copied the MinGW folder into the same installation directory, However even though I did exactly as you said above, the message still pops up. At this point,  I am confused if the "first option" that you have mentioned above is the : "GNU GCC for ARM".?

Comment: It prompts me with an environment error, saying, "can't find the compiler executable in your configured search path for GNU GCC compiler for ARM."

Comment: In the third image you posted, above "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010", there should be an option for "GNU GCC Compiler" (without any "for" part).  Use that option.

Comment: it did it exactly!! Thanks!!